# CIDetector with CIDetectorTypeQRCode works on iPad but not on iPhone and iPod

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, cidetector

When I try to use the `CIDetector` to read QR codes on the iPhone or iPod, the detector always returns `nil`:

```
NSDictionary *detectorOptions = @{@"CIDetectorAccuracy": @"CIDetectorAccuracyHigh"};

CIDetector * detector = [CIDetector  detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeQRCode context:nil options:detectorOptions];
```

Running this code on an iPad works. 
All devices are on iOS 9, using Xcode 7.0.1

Other detectors work fine, like face detection succeeds:

```
detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:detectorOptions];
```

Is there an extra setting / library to get the QRCode detector working on the iPhone / iPod?

Comment: What are the device exactly? Are you scanning the exact same image? For example, if it's from Camera, the camera may be too poor to scan for small QRCode, and that's different for each device.

Comment: My issue is not that the detector does not find the qr code in an image; the issue is that the CIDetector does not even instantiate on my physical iPhone 5 and on iPod 5th generation, only on my iPad Air 2. I added the exact hardware versions as this could be a GPU related issue?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, i have tried with ipad and iphone, i cant get to instantiate the CIDetector in CIDetectorTypeQRCode mode.

Comment: I got CIDetector nil when detect QR code in iPad. Let me know proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, base on my testing, it doesn't work on touch. But works well on iPhone and iPad.

Comment: It does not work on my iPhone 5 but works on the 6 Plus.Maybe it only works on units with fingerprint scanner?